# Merging hexagons in grid

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, polygon, hexagonal-tiles

I have a hexagon grid that I'm drawing with HTML canvas with different type values with corresponding colours. I want to combine the hexagons that neighbour other hexagons with the same type. This is my current function:

```
drawGrid() {

        lineCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const size = mapContainer.zoom * 100;

        const rect = mapContainer.getViewedHexes();

        let hexList = [];

        for (let row = rect.top; row < rect.bottom; row++) {
                
            for (let col = rect.left; col < rect.right; col++) {

                hexList.push({
                    points: hexPoints(hexCenter(size, row, col), size, size),
                    row: row,
                    col: col,
                    type: mapContainer.hexGrid[row][col]
                }); 
                
            }
    
        }

        //Combine the hexes where they neighbour the same type, the way the hexes are drawn is in the odd-r horizontal layout where the odd rows are shoved right.

        hexList.forEach(hex => {
            this.drawPolygon(hex.points, "rgba(255,0,0, 0.4)");
        });

    }
```

Also feel free to critique my javascript code as I have a lot to learn.

These are some of the functions that I've used to create my hex grid if you would like to see them:

```
function hexPoints(center, height, width) {

    const points = [];

    for (let i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
        points[i] = hexCorner(center, height / 2, width / 2, i);
    }

    //Point 0 is the top right corner
    //Point 1 is the bottom right corner
    //Point 2 is the bottom middle corner
    //Point 3 is the bottom left corner
    //Point 4 is the top left corner
    //Point 5 is the top middle corner

    return points;

}

function hexCorner(center, height, width, i) {
    const angleDeg = 60 * i - 30;
    const angleRad = Math.PI / 180 * angleDeg;
    const x = center.x + width * Math.cos(angleRad);
    const y = center.y + height * Math.sin(angleRad);
    return { x, y };
}

function hexCenter(size, row, col) {
    
    let offset = 0;

    if (row % 2 === 1) {
        offset = Math.sqrt(3) * size / 4
    }

    const w = Math.sqrt(3) * size / 2;
    const h = 3/2 * size / 2;
    const x = w * col + offset + w / 2 + mapContainer.mapX;
    const y = h * row + h / (3/2) + mapContainer.mapY;

    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };

}
```

Comment: Great resource: [Red Blob Games ~ Hexagonal Grids](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) (very interactive)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, I used that resource to construct my grid and hexagons however I don't believe that it has information on how to do this.

Comment: What does `mapContainer` look like? All I know is that it has `hexGrid` and `zoom` properties and a `getViewHexes()` method. Including a full example would help out others.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl mapContainer is simply an object that contains entities, the hexagon grid and terrain. It also contains info on the location of the grid, zoom, movement and such.

Comment: Can you at the very least include the `hexCenter` and `hexPoints` functions?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I have added these functions to help other people if they want.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to "visually" merge? Then simply skip stroking the path.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('#grid').getContext('2d');

const TAU = 2 * Math.PI;
const EDGES = 6;

const mapContainer = {
  hexGrid: [
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  ],
  zoom: 0.25,
  getViewedHexes: function() {
    return {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 5,
      right: 5
    };
  }
};

drawGrid();

// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72663019/1762224
function drawGrid() {
  const size = Math.floor(mapContainer.zoom * 100);
  const rect = mapContainer.getViewedHexes();
  const dimensions = getDimensions(size);
  const points = hexPoints(size);
  for (let gy = rect.top; gy < rect.bottom - rect.top; gy++) {
    for (let gx = rect.left; gx < rect.right - rect.left; gx++) {
      const color = typeToColor(mapContainer.hexGrid[gy][gx]);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      drawPolygon(hexCenter(gx, gy, size), points);
    }
  }
}

function typeToColor(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case 1:
      return 'grey';
    case 2:
      return 'yellow';
    case 0:
    default:
      return 'white';
  }
}

function hexCenter(gx, gy, size) {
  const { grid } = getDimensions(size);
  return {
    x: (gx + 1) * grid.space.x,
    y: (gy + 1) * grid.space.y + (gx % 2 ? grid.offset.y : 0)
  };
}

function drawPolygon(p, points) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, p.x, p.y);
  const [{ x: startX, y: startY }] = points;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  points.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  });
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function hexPoints(size, sides = EDGES, points = []) {
  const step = TAU / sides;
  let ang = 0, i = sides;
  while (i--) {
    points.push(toPoint(size * Math.cos(ang), size * Math.sin(ang)));
    ang += step;
  }
  return points;
}

function getDimensions(radius, edges = EDGES) {
  const
    edgeLength = Math.sin(Math.PI / edges) * radius * 2,
    gridSpaceX = radius * 2 - edgeLength * 0.5,
    gridSpaceY = Math.cos(Math.PI / edges) * radius * 2,
    gridOffsetY = gridSpaceY * 0.5;
  return {
    edgeLength,
    grid: {
      space: {
        x: gridSpaceX,
        y: gridSpaceY
      },
      offset: {
        y: gridOffsetY
      }
    }
  };
}

function toPoint(x, y) {
  return ({ x, y });
}
```

```css
#grid { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

```html
<canvas id="grid" width="260" height="260"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes I know however this won't work as I'm not only trying to visually merge but actually merge. I'm doing this as the ctx.fill() is extremely inefficient and is the thing that uses the majority of resources in my project. I figure that if I combine the hexes into bigger polygons that will reduce the resources required.